# Compute the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Compute the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

Can you give me a hint on how to approach these kind of exercises?

Comment: $z\mapsto e^z$ is a covering map from $\Bbb{C}$ to $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Why is it a universal cover? Use $1$ as a basepoint.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loops in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ are completely characterised up to homotopy by how many times they wind around $0$, which can be any integer. Furthermore, adding two loops with winding numbers $a$ and $b$ produces a loop with winding number $a+b$. Therefore the fundamental group of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 5):

$\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ has the circle $S^1$ as a deformation retract.   Thus $\pi_1(\Bbb C\setminus\{0\})=\pi_1(S^1)=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: What is meant by "deformation retract"? That there exists a homotopy between $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and $S^1$?

Comment: It implies the existence of a homotopy.